# Can't connect with ODBC (MAC)

Tags: mysql, macos, odbc, pyodbc

Hello I tried to connect a MySql Database with `pyodbc` but always get this Error:

> ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I'm using macOS, installed the python library, made the Database "teefabrik".

This is my Code

```
import pyodbc

connection_string = (
'DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver;'
'SERVER=localhost;'
'DATABASE=teefabrik;'
'UID=root;'
'PWD=;'
'charset=utf8mb4;'
)

conn=pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: @GordThompson the list is empty

Comment: Okay, so the ODBC driver is not installed. Installing pyodbc does not automatically install the required driver(s) because it does not know which one(s) you need. You can download the MySQL driver [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).

Comment: I did this but the list is still empty